# How to mock jQuery selector in google JS Test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing

I've started using google js test and have become stuck trying to unit test the jquery selector below - actualy i want to check that the append function has been called but that requires a selector.

'JQuery' is the jQuery ($) object that i inject into a function.

```
JQuery('#' + containerElementId).append('some html');
```

I have created an object that I use as a mock for jQuery
this.jQuery = {
        append: createMockFunction()
    };

I would like to test that append is called:

```
expectCall(this.jQuery(_).append)();
-OR-
expectCall(this.jQuery('#fakeselector').append)();
```

This gives me the error:
TypeError: Property 'jQuery' of object # is not a function
FAILED

What do i need to do to the this.jQuery object literal to get around the selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that you can create a mock like this:

```
var jqueryEmptyStub = {
    append: createMockFunction()
};

var jQueryMock = function (rootSelector) {
    return jqueryEmptyStub;
};

var myObject = anObject(jQueryMock );
expectCall(jqueryEmptyStub.append)();
myObject.doSomethingThatCallsAppend();
```